# Fixing autocompletion in extremely simple PhpStorm example

Tags: phpstorm

I've just downloaded and installed PhpStorm 7.1, and I'm wondering why it won't understand the following piece of code:

```
<?php


/**
 * Class Whatever
 */
class Whatever {

  /**
   * Just prints "Hello."
   */
  function foo() {
    echo "Hello.\n";
  }
}


$test = new Whatever();

$test->foo();

?>
```

It appears to ignore the `Whatever` class definition.

When typing `$this->` and pressing Ctrl+Enter it says "`No suggestions`" and after typing `new` the `Whatever` class is never part of the suggestion list. In some other cases I can't currently reproduced it said something like "`Undefined class definition: Whateer`".

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

See the following screenshot. Please note the message in the bottom left corner after typing `$test->foo`.

[image: screenshot showing PhpStorm error message]

Also, this is what happens when I press `Ctrl+B`:

[image: screenshot showing that PhpStrom can't find the declaration of "foo"]

**However**, pressing `Ctrl+B` with the caret at `new Whatever` finds the class and the same works when using `Ctrl+B` on `$test` itself... Weird...

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* Possibly nothing. 1) Have you tried `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart? 2) Is this the only `Whatever` class in your project? 3) Any 3rd party plugins? Maybe one of them is interfering somehow. I do not what else could be wrong for such basic code sample (it works fine for much complex classes on my setup).

Comment: 1) just tried, no improvement. 2) yes, I don't have any real projects set up yet, as I'm just trying to get familiar with PhpStorm. I just created an empty project, created "test.php" and played around with Code Style Rules in the project settings, nothing more 3) no plugins configured/used

Comment: FYI, I've just added screenshots that illustrate the problem.

Comment: 1st screenshot -- message is correct -- you do not have field `foo` in your class. I definitely cannot reproduce this on my working 7.1.3 setup. Could you zip whole project, upload and share the link? maybe something whith your project config? I may also suggest to try v8 (EAP stage ATM) -- maybe it will be better for you: http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm

Comment: I think I found the problem: The test file was saved outside the project folder (different drive). Using `Save as...` and saving it to the project root folder immediately solved the problem. Seems still strange to me, though. BTW, now the message in the first screenshot does not appear anymore. Instead, PhpStorm brings up a popup showing the `foo` method with it's (empty) parameter list - as expected.

Comment: Yes -- that's how PhpStorm works (always been like that, since v0.x) -- it shows errors for valid code if file is outside of the project (not referenced via `PHP Include Paths` or `Directories`). Not sure if this is a bug or what -- but no one has complained (even if complained -- the issue was put in backlog as not important).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had my test file outside the project folder. As LazyOne pointed out, this is how PhpStorm works. Moving the file to the project dir solved the problem

See also the comments to the question..